# interactively work with xy point plot clusters - group manipulation in r

Tags: r, graph, plot, interactive, rggobi

I have a large number of pair of X and Y variables along with their cluster membership column. Cluster membership (group) may not be always right (limitation in perfection of clustering algorithm), I want to interactively visualize the clusters and manipulate the cluster memberships to identified points.

I tried rggobi and the following is the point I was able to get to (I do not mean that I need to use rggobi / ggobi, if better options are available you are welcome to suggest).

```
# data
set.seed (1234)
c1 <- rnorm (40, 0.1, 0.02); c2 <- rnorm (40, 0.3, 0.01)
c3 <- rnorm (40, 0.5, 0.01); c4 <- rnorm (40, 0.7, 0.01)
c5 <- rnorm (40, 0.9, 0.03)
Yv <- 0.3 + rnorm (200, 0.05, 0.05)
myd <- data.frame (Xv = round (c(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5), 2), Yv = round (Yv, 2),
 cltr = factor (rep(1:5, each = 40)))

require(rggobi)
g <- ggobi(myd)
display(g[1], vars=list(X="Xv", Y="Yv"))
```

[image]

You can see five clusters, colored differently with **cltr** variable. I manually identified the points that are outliers and I want to make their value to NA in the cltr variable. Is their any easy way to disassociate such membership and write to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `identify` to get the indices of the points manually:

```
## use base::plot
plot(myd$Xv, myd$Yv, col=myd$cltr)

exclude <- identify(myd$Xv, myd$Yv) ## left click on the points you want to exclude (right click to stop/finish)

myd$cltr[exclude] <- NA
```

Comment: cool, thanks. May be I would just replace cltr value to NA (without removing Xv, Yv, from plot - but  myd$cltr[exclude] <- NA is not working, any idea ?

Comment: Please do not say "... is not working". Instead offer the error message.